# Получение связанной таблицы через промежуточную

Tags: laravel

Есть 4 таблицы: products, categorys, category_products и images( связанна с products)
Каким способом можно получить изображения для каждого товара.

#categoryController

```
public function category($slug) {
    $category = Category::find(2);
    $brands = Brand::whereIn('id', [1, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12])->get();
    return view('front.catalog.index', compact('image', 'category', 'brands'));
}
```

#Category Model

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'category_products');
}
```

#template
Вывод всего товара этой категории и здесь нужно к каждому товару подставить соответствующее изображение которое хранится в Image

```
@foreach($category->products as $product)
     @include('layouts/front/card', compact('product'))
@endforeach
```

Comment: попробуйте заменить на return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');

Comment: @ktscript Проблема не в этом. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как можно вытащить из таблицы images необходимую картинку в цикле foreach как выше. Потому что он возвращает коллекцию, а через коллекцию нельзя обращаться к методам моделей ( в моем случае к методу images модели product)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавив в модель Product метод getImage, и теперь эта модель имеет следующий вид

```
class Product extends Model
```

{
protected $fillable = ['brand_id', 'article', 'name', 'slug', 'description', 'color', 'season', 'price', 'provider'];

```
protected $with = ['images'];


public function images() {
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}


public function getImage() {
    foreach ($this->images as $img) {
        return $img->img_one;
    }
}
```

}

Изображения в шаблоне вывожу вот так

```
@foreach($category->products as $product)
 <img src="{{ $product->getImage() }}" alt="photo" class="img-reponsive">
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены, что ваше решение работает верно?
Исходя из кода, `getImage()` вернёт только 1 изображение.

Если я правильно понял задачу, вам следуюет использовать отношение Has Many Through
Подробнее о ней можно прочесть тут: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through